# How to dismiss dialog from within anonymous class?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a custom dialog class that extends Android's `Dialog`. Now I have a button in this dialog that is supposed to load another fragment and dismiss dialog, so I passed anonymous `Button.OnclickListener` that loads fragment but can't dismiss the dialog since I can't access it's object. What should I do?

```
BallsDialog dialog = new BallsDialog(this);
            dialog.setTitle("asd");
            dialog.setText("asd");

            dialog.setAgainButtonOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("levels", String.valueOf(levelList.size()));
                    RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.BallsRelativeLayout);
                    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.horizontal_background_main);

                    Fragment fragment = new LevelFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    fm.executePendingTransactions();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: ofcourse you can access dialog object within your onclick method. declare your dialog object as final e.g. **final  BallsDialog dialog = new BallsDialog(this);** and then in your onClick method write **dialog.dismiss();** after  **fm.executePendingTransactions();**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you cannot make the outer object final, you can still access it via a qualified this:

```
BallsDialog.this.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem, here is the answer.
Make dialog object final and then you can use it inside anonymous class.